# Nginx Doesn't Work After Compiling from Source and Installing

Tags: nginx, compilation, sudo

I've compiled and installed `nginx` from source with three easy commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now when I try to run `nginx` under my default user, I get this message:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

It also doesn't work with `sudo` with a pretty strange error:

```
sudo: nginx: command not found
```

So does anybody know: What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Have you tried `su -` typing your password and then running `nginx`?

Comment: Yes, it also leads me to 'command not found' error

Comment: Have you created a symbolic link to your `nginx` in /usr/bin? If yes, perhaps you should add `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'` to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Nope, isn't working. I've tried to do something with $PATH, no result at all

Comment: Then try the following: `sudo ln -s /path/to/your/compiled/nginx/binary /usr/sbin/nginx`.

Comment: Still no result — 'command not found' :( With sudo/root it only runs from `/usr/local/nginx/sbin` directory with `./nginx` command

Comment: Thank God! Now it works, I just added `/usr/local/nginx/sbin` to /etc/environment. Thank you a lot, Luka!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `/usr/local/nginx/sbin` to your `PATH` variable in `/etc/environment`.